# Symfony crawler get text with following-sibling

Tags: symfony, laravel, xpath

Given the following html code:

```
<div class="body">
    1. Question <strong>1</strong>
    <input type="text" />
    2. You have <u>Question</u><strong>1</strong>
    <input type="text" />
    3. Question <strong>3</strong>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

I want get the text like this:

```
[
   0 => 'Question 1', // Or 'Question <strong>1</strong>' is better
   1 => 'You have Question 2',
   2 => 'Question 3'
]
```

This is my code:

```
$results = [];
$questions = $crawler->filterXPath('//*[contains(@class, "body")]/text()[normalize-space()][following-sibling::input]');
$questions = $questions->each(function($c) use (&$results) {
    $line = trim($c->text());
    if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,2}\./', $line, $matches) == true) {
        $number = $matches[0];
        if(is_numeric($number) && $number != '') {
            $results[] = trim(str_replace($number, '', $line));
        }
    } elseif(!empty($results)) {
        $results[count($results) - 1] .= '\n'. $line;
    }
});

return $results;
```

It works fine without `<strong>` and `<u>` tag. How whould you do it exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip_tags($text) to remove html from the strings

read about it here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp

If you want to remove the starting number, you can use explode() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like

```
explode(' ', $line, 2)
```

notice the "2" at the end, this will produce and array of 2 elemets, first of which will be the number + the dot, second will be the text.